# Explaining a quote from KDAB blog

Tags: qt, opengl

I am reading [OpenGL in Qt 5.1](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/) from [KDAB](http://www.kdab.com/). They say regarding OpenGL:

> ...the need to resolve entry point addresses dynamically at runtime
>   rather than the build time linker being able to do so.

What does that mean precisely and why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to explain what is going on here is that on most platforms (OS X is an exception to the rule), they ship with a very primitive implementation of OpenGL (1.1 on Windows) and it is the responsibility of hardware (and sometimes software) drivers to extend OpenGL.

Because it would not benefit anyone to have to link your program explicitly to every possible combination of drivers (and re-compile and link your program whenever a new driver version is released) what actually happens is this: the version of the OpenGL run-time that ships with the platform has a mechanism for loading extension function addresses from another installed component (driver) at run-time. You do not need to know who wrote the driver or what version it is, you merely ask the platform's OpenGL library to communicate with the driver and return the address of a function that the library itself does not implement.

In this way, the base library (which is effectively a stub these days, since a great deal of OpenGL 1.1 is deprecated) only has to be written once. You still cannot be sure what your host machine will support until run-time, because the feature set provided depends on the installed driver.

I mentioned OS X earlier, and I will take some time to explain how it is different. On OS X, the library actually includes functions for every extension that ***Apple*** has implemented (Apple itself implements the display drivers on OS X) on the platform. That is, simply by linking against the proper Framework you have access to every function. However, if the function cannot be implemented on the hardware/software configuration, attempting to call any of these functions will generate a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error at run-time.

That is the difference between link-time and run-time resolution - on OS X all functions are resolved at link-time, but that does not mean they are useable. On other platforms, extended functions are resolved at run-time through an installed 3rd party driver. Since it is more common for the driver to be implemented by a 3rd party than the party who developed the platform, the second case is far more common.

Answer (score 3):

The KDAB article gives the very explanation:

> … **the address of any function introduced since OpenGL 1.1 must be resolved at run-time**

OpenGL is not a library, it's an API, i.e. a set of functions that are provided. Some part of the API have been defined to be always presented by the operating system *interface* libraries. Since this is fixed, it can be resolved  at link time.

In Microsoft Windows all the functions of OpenGL-1.1 are part of that. However everything that was introduced to OpenGL later on, i.e. newer versions of OpenGL *and* extensions, are not present in that interface library (which is somewhat a smallest common denominator on the supported featureset).

Since the version and features supported depend on the installed GPU and driver, which change from system to system, pointers to all the additional functions must be obtained at runtime using dynamically. As there is no difference in loading extensions or a new version feature set, either happens through the very same mechanism.

Comment: Your quote is just the same thing I quoted in my question...but for windows. So nothing new here^^ Also, if you make the difference between library and API, then we are talking about a set of functions *specification*. But, if the drivers respect this specification, there should not be any problem... But, this is not the case as you stated so we need some kind mechanism to "translate" between "normal" OpenGL (the one I am writing) and the "driver" opengl. Is this what we are talking about?

Comment: @Korchkidu: IS this really so hard to understand: The operating system gives you an interface between your program and the drivers. New hardware and drivers may introduce functions that were not present when the OS level interface was created. To avoid having to go through a full operating system update the interface allows to load functionality from the drivers even if it wasn't present at the time the interface library was created. Since you want to be able to use the OS with a large variety of hardware, the interface library is written to the lowest version that you want to assert available

Comment: @Korchkidu: It doesn't matter if Windows or not. Linux, Solaris and FreeBSD do it all the same. Only MacOS X doesn't expose an extension mechanism and needs a full OS upgrade to support newer versions of OpenGL. Which essentially means that MacOS X lags about 2 years behind OpenGL development. Windows, Linux, Solaris and BSD are all up-to-date because their driver architecture allows extension.

Comment: @Korchkidu: Also drivers "following" the specification misses the point. Your application needs to be able to talk to the drivers. And that it can do only through the interface provided by the OS. But if an OS would provide a interface library featuring the full OpenGL-4.4 feature set, the minimum requirements for a GPU to be useable on this OS is a OpenGL-4.4 capable GPU. Hence you want to keep the interface to the driver as low in its version as possible and load newer and extended functionality only at runtime, because otherwise you're severely limiting the set of supported GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

You should have read it further. It gives an example why that cannot be done by the linker during the build time:

> ... For example, on Microsoft Windows, the address of any function introduced since OpenGL 1.1 must be resolved at run-time. That is nearly all of functions used in a modern OpenGL application! ...

The article also explains that the proc address and the functions, et al will need to be solved during the runtime by proper query and helper functionality.

> ... To assist with this Qt has provided a couple of helpful utilities: QOpenGLContext::getProcAddress() and QOpenGLFunctions. ...

Keep read the article on!

Comment: your not explaining, your are just rephrasing. What's the difference between OpenGL and any other library? Why can't we link to functions like any other lib?

Comment: @Korchkidu: uh, I think you slightly misunderstood the topic of the article. It is not about linking against opengl or not, it is about resolving runtime depedent implementations.

Comment: "resolve entry point addresses" + "the build time linker". It really looks like they are talking about linking. Can you elaborate by giving a precise example on what's the problem is and why that please?

Comment: @Korchkidu: I am not sure I understand what you are asking, but how would you solve the aforementioned Microsoft case for instance without runtime resolution?

Comment: Just to be sure, are we talking about extensions? I doubt it because they introduce extensions in the next section. Also, is this something particular to OpenGL 2.0 (which I do not know)?

Comment: @Korchkidu: Here goes the point again here: "For example, on Microsoft Windows, the address of any function introduced since OpenGL 1.1 must be resolved at run-time.". So, no, this is not just about OpenGL ES. That has to be solved at run-time. You have no choice. What is the problem? :)

Comment: I ask "What A / Why A?" and you answer "Because A on windows"... That's not helping much. I am confused because I started playing with OpenGL 4 and never faced such "difficulties". I mainly do not see the differences  with "normal" shared libraries... I am just confused and it will hopefully be crystal clear tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Korchkidu: you realize that extension functionality and features from newer versions cannot be solved by link-time as it is unknown in certain scenarios? You have no other way than solving it at runtime. Seems you have always used the old and very basic functionality or a platform where everything was automagically present. Either way, I would suggest to take a look at the Windows example mentioned, finally!

Comment: That would help if you could point the main differences with using a shared library for example. As stated here, that's the same so hard to see why such a complex mechanism would be required. But if we take the driver dependency into account, then it could explain... Still confused though. And indeed, I have been automagically using OpenGL under windows 7. I call an opengl function, and it works;) Like any other library though;)

Comment: Well yes, that's why I thought it was about extensions. But it is not apparently. Also, I do not see what is so specific compared to using shared libraries.. I am still confused^^' Surely something obvious I do not understand...

Comment: @Korchkidu: OpenGL is not a library. It's a spec. Yes there is a `opengl32.dll` or a `libGL.so`, but those are merely conduits into the actual driver. Those interface library are the same on all systems and not touched by the driver in any way. In fact on Windows the `opengl32.dll` has been all the same for over 15 years.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I never forced you to answer... You can browse somewhere else, no problem...;)

Comment: @Korchkidu: I know, but I hope you now got all the understanding from me and datenwolf you needed.